# Can't resume after *second* suspend in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, suspend, hibernate

I used to be able to suspend/resume without issues in previous Ubuntu versions, but since upgrading to 20.04 I can only resume *once*. After trying to resume for the *second time*, the computer doesn't really resume, the screen doesn't show anything and can't even access any other terminals with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`number`, so I have to force restart by pressing the restart button. Note that after I resume for the first time after a fresh restart everything works fine.

Some additional info:

- NVIDIA Driver: 460.32.03 (`nvidia-driver-460`)
- Linux Kernel: 5.4.0-62-generic
- OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8

Could someone give me a hand with this? Thanks!

Comment: am also looking for a solution to this ... I have seen this same issue appear then go away over the years of using this combination of Ubuntu and the current Nvidia driver so I feel your pain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experience the same problem with 455 and 460 branches. The only one working fine is the legacy branch 390. Therefore you could try switching to nvidia-driver-390, if your hardware is appropriate and driver capabilities are enough for you. For instance, you won't be able to use the newest CUDA toolkit anymore. See [supported NVIDIA cards](https://www.nvidia.de/Download/driverResults.aspx/168417/en).

Comment: Wow, this totally worked. Thank you so much!